# Are [tasks] and [todo] synonymous?

Tags: discussion, tags

Both [tasks](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tasks) and [todo](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/todo) are being used to mean the same thing.

Which do you think should be the master tag?

Answer (score 1):

To me, they mean different things.  A task is always a todo.  A todo is not always a task.  A task is the input, a todo is the output or result.

Personally, I'd use [tasks].  I don't have any compelling reasons why other than the above.

Comment: I agree I would just use tasks.